# On dit "quand même" ou "comme même" ?

Tags: orthographe

Je me demande souvent, est-ce que j'écris "comme même" ou bien "quand même" ?

ps: I am not an native french speaker

Comment: I've seen a lot of that mistake recently made by (most of the time young) native speakers, I wonders where it comes from as the pronunciation is even quite different...

Comment: Well i dont know :s

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C'est "Quand même".

Par exemple: "Les pauvres gens ne soupçonnent jamais le diable, quand même il les tiendrait à la gorge. (Johann Wolfgang von Goethe)"

Pour vous en souvenir vous pouvez vous rappeler que:
"*Quand même*" est similaire à "*Quand bien même*"

"Quand bien même il pleuvrait, je serais présent."

"Tu m'a blessé mais je t'aime quand même" : Quand bien même tu m'a blessé, je t'ai aimé.

Comment: intéressant  .... :)

Comment: C'est pas un peu bizarre de dire "Quand bien même"?

Answer (score 1):

Our French friends (in their late 50's) insist there is no such thing as  "comme meme", but I knew I had seen it. Google translate does not recognise it, but Reverso French-English dictionary does have some examples" viz
 « Nous ne sommes pas sûrs, mais nous prenons comme même le chemin le plus risqué ».
 “We’re not sure, but let’s take the riskiest road anyway.”
C'est la fille de Taylor. Je peux comme même pas...
It's Taylor's daughter. I can't just...

Pourtant tu n'as rien fait de mal, mais Jenna part comme même.
You did nothing wrong, but Jenna left, anyway.
On n'a pas besoin de son aide Faisons le comme même.
We don't need his help. Let's just do it.

Vous agissez comme même, mais... vous voulez juste aider les gens.
You act all tough, but... you really just want to help people.

Comme même ça ne réussit pas toujours, il lui arrive de devoir acheter de l’eau.
Since sometimes even that is not successful, she is often forced to buy water.

Comment: Aucun des exemples n'est correct.

Comment: Not all in their late 50's at all ... _comme même_ still unknown. Never heard it.

Comment: Sue, reverso is not a reference. This is really where one just has know the language. There is quasi-homophony (they almost sound alike) between the two which is why those who are not well educated might get it wrong....The only correct way to write it: quand même.

Comment: It's one of the famous mistakes often encountered on social networks, very famous lately. We even make fun of it by using it ironically, sometimes it's hard to tell if it's done on purpose or not. Check "comme meme" on Google Images, we have memes for that.

Comment: I'm 20 and I assure you "Comme même" has never existed ;) It's just a mistake that has been made so many times that some people actually believe this is the right way to say/write it.